# How to compute $\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{x^5 e^{-1/x^2}+x/2 - \sin(x/2))}{x^3})$?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I have a problem with this limit. I have no idea where is the problem.
Can you correct my mistake? Thanks

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x^5 e^\frac{-1}{x^2}+\frac{x}{2} - \sin(\frac{x}{2})}{x^3}\right)$$

I used the developments of McLaurin $e^x$ and $\sin x$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x^5 (1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{2x^4})+\frac{x}{2} - ((\frac{x}{2})-(\frac{x^3}{48}))}{x^3}\right) = 
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x^5-x^3+ \frac{x}{2} +\frac{x}{2} - \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^3}{48}}{x^3}\right)=$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{-x^3+\frac{x^3}{48}}{x^3}\right)= 
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{-\frac{47x^3}{48}}{x^3}\right)=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(-\frac{47x^3}{48x^3}\right)= -\frac{47}{48}$$

but the result is wrong.

Comment: it should be $\frac{1}{48}$

Comment: i know but howw

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that this limit could be evaluated purely by using L'Hopital? I suppose it would take a long time (you'd have to use the product rule many times), but could it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may write, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^5 e^{-\frac1{x^2}}+\frac{x}{2} - \sin(\frac{x}{2})}{x^3}&=\frac{x^5 e^{-\frac1{x^2}}+\frac{x}{2} - \left(\frac{x}2-\frac{x^3}{48}+O(x^5)\right)}{x^3}\\\\
&=\frac{x^5 e^{-\frac1{x^2}} + \frac{x^3}{48}+O(x^5)}{x^3}\\\\
&=\frac{x^2 e^{-\frac1{x^2}} + \frac{1}{48}+O(x^2)}{1}\\\\
&=  \frac{1}{48}+O(x^2)\\\\
\end{align}
$$ giving $\dfrac{1}{48}$ for the sought limit, where we have used $\displaystyle x^2 e^{-\frac1{x^2}}=O(x^2)$ (to say the least).

Comment: so I dont need to develop the e^x ?

Comment: No -- even keeping it as an $o(1)$, you still have a remaining $x^2$ in front that guarantees that term can be discarded. Note that there is no "good" expansion of the exponential anyway -- its argument goes to $-\infty$.

Comment: @Amarildo You can not expand $\displaystyle e^{-\frac1{x^2}} $as you did, because the terms $\displaystyle O\left(\frac{1}{x^{2n}}\right)$ are **not small** as $x \to 0$. are you OK with this fact?

Comment: ok i got it thanks

Answer (score 1):

Setting $y=x^{-1}$, it is equivalent to
$$
y^3 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{e^{y^2}y^5}+\frac{1}{2y}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{2y}\right)\right) \approx y^3 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2y}-\left(\frac{1}{2y}-\frac{1}{48y^3}\right)\right)
$$
as $y\to \infty$. Conclude.